# Show that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges, given that $|a_n-a_{n+1}|\leq\lambda\ |a_{n-1}-a_n| $

Tags: real-analysis

"Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence and $\lambda\in(0,1)$, where:
$|a_n-a_{n+1}|\leq\lambda\ |a_{n-1}-a_n| $
Show that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges."

I found this question in an Analysis past paper and I am having some difficulties, but this is what I have so far:
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$|a_n-a_{n+1}|\leq\lambda\ |a_{n-1}-a_n| $
$\iff$ $\frac{|a_n-a_{n+1}|} {|a_{n-1}-a_n|}\leq \lambda\lt 1$
$\implies $ $|a_n-a_{n+1}|\lt |a_{n-1}-a_n| $   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $  $(*)$
Let $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence of the differences of one term to the next in $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, then according to $(*)$, $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is strictly monotonically decreasing.

This is where I am stuck, because I believe I would need to show that $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is converging to $0$, for $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to be convergent, however I have no way of making $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge to $0$, therefore my approach is probably wrong.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You want to use the fact that you have a uniform contraction for every difference (given by $\lambda$). Also, in trying to show that the $b_n$’s go to 0, what are you trying to prove about the sequence $(a_n)$?

Comment: Let $p$ and $q$ be integers larger than $n$. Can you say something interesting about $\vert a_p - a_q\vert$ depending only on $n$ ?

Comment: Your problem lies in the implication $\implies$ in $(*)$. What you have left is a statement that is too weak to reach your conclusion; consider for instance $a_i = \log(i)$. That tells you that you really need to use $\lambda$ itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the given condition it follows

- $|a_n - a_{n+1}| \leq \lambda^n|a_0 - a_1|$ with $\lambda \in (0,1)$
- $\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n - a_{n-1})$ is absolutely convergent
- With $a_n = a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k - a_{k-1})$ it follows the convergence of $(a_n)$, since $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k - a_{k-1})$ is convergent.

Comment: Could you please explain why $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_n - a_{n-1})$ is absolutely convergent? thanks

Comment: Because $\sum \lambda^n$ is a convergent geometric series.

Comment: @user639631 :
Because:
\begin{eqnarray*} |\sum_{n=1}^N (a_n - a_{n-1})| 
& \leq & \sum_{n=1}^N |a_n - a_{n-1}| \\
& \leq & \sum_{n=1}^N \lambda^{n-1}|a_1 - a_0| \\
& \leq & |a_1 - a_0| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda^{n-1} \\
& = & \frac{1}{1-\lambda}
\end{eqnarray*}